# Using shuffle.js with checkboxes and unoredered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I came across shuffle.js and it seems perfect for a project I'm doing.

What I have is a list of checkboxes, as well as an unordered list which users should be able to click on to filter results.

I have seen many good examples of the use of shuffle.js but they all seem abstract.

```
    // JavaScript Document

    var shuffleme = (function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  var $grid = $('#grid'), //locate what we want to sort 
      $filterOptions = $('.portfolio-sorting li'),  //locate the filter categories
      $sizer = $grid.find('.shuffle_sizer'),    //sizer stores the size of the items

  init = function() {

    // None of these need to be executed synchronously
    setTimeout(function() {
      listen();
      setupFilters();
    }, 100);

    // instantiate the plugin
    $grid.shuffle({
      itemSelector: '[class*="col-"]',
      sizer: $sizer    
    });
  },



  // Set up button clicks
  setupFilters = function() {
    var $btns = $filterOptions.children();
    $btns.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
          isActive = $this.hasClass( 'active' ),
          group = isActive ? 'all' : $this.data('group');

      // Hide current label, show current label in title
      if ( !isActive ) {
        $('.portfolio-sorting li a').removeClass('active');
      }

      $this.toggleClass('active');

      // Filter elements
      $grid.shuffle( 'shuffle', group );
    });

    $btns = null;
  },

  // Re layout shuffle when images load. This is only needed
  // below 768 pixels because the .picture-item height is auto and therefore
  // the height of the picture-item is dependent on the image
  // I recommend using imagesloaded to determine when an image is loaded
  // but that doesn't support IE7
  listen = function() {
    var debouncedLayout = $.throttle( 300, function() {
      $grid.shuffle('update');
    });

    // Get all images inside shuffle
    $grid.find('img').each(function() {
      var proxyImage;

      // Image already loaded
      if ( this.complete && this.naturalWidth !== undefined ) {
        return;
      }

      // If none of the checks above matched, simulate loading on detached element.
      proxyImage = new Image();
      $( proxyImage ).on('load', function() {
        $(this).off('load');
        debouncedLayout();
      });

      proxyImage.src = this.src;
    });

    // Because this method doesn't seem to be perfect.
    setTimeout(function() {
      debouncedLayout();
    }, 500);
  };      

  return {
    init: init
  };
}( jQuery ));

$(document).ready(function()
{
  shuffleme.init(); //filter portfolio
});
```

So this is the code sample that I have seen online and I have been studying it.

If i wanted to use check boxes could I just set the value of each checkbox to the name of the group I'm filtering?

Interestingly, it works on HTML pages, but not PHP.